# reactnative : can't get ellipsizeMode to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to truncate a text in my reactnative app. I've decided to use the "ellipsizeMode" attribute, but I can't get it to work.

I wrote a demo of the problem :

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';


export class EllipsizeModeTest extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{'first part | '}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                    {'a text too long to be displayed on the screen'}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20,
    }
});
```

Now the text does not get truncated, any idea why ?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, it's enough to have the size of the element bound to a value. So if you define width, or add a flex value will work.

```
<View style={{width: 200}}><Text ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1}></View>
```

Comment: Just adding `flex: 1` did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width on your Text element so it knows when to ... it

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20,
        width: 100
    }
});
```

[image: Then you get this]

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning a string to `ellipsizeMode` (remove the curly brackets):

```
<Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a width style property to the  component

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';


export class EllipsizeModeTest extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{'first part | '}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>
                    {'a text too long to be displayed on the screen'}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20,
        width: 100
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this But did not get the ellipsis, instead, the text was abruptly cut.